# Select flash in com_banners

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, file-upload, com-banners

I have problem with flash files in com_banners. When I select "image", I can upload flash file but I can't choose flash because it's not on the list. I can put manualy path but it's not good idea for client.

In mod_banners is line : `<?php elseif (BannerHelper::isFlash($imageurl)) :?>` so I am confused why mod_media in com_banners it does not allow to select .swf file.

Is there any way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this same problem with JCE Editor and Media Manager plugin:

- JCE Editor https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/
- Media manager https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/plugins/media-manager

Now, all files are listed and i can select any file.